# Why this char driver always copies just one byte?

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver

I was fiddling around with a scull driver code, and in turn tried to make it print the whole characters entered, instead of one.That is:

```
# insmod memory.ko
# chmod 666 /dev/memory
$ echo -n abcdef >/dev/memory
$ cat /dev/memory
```

should print abcdef, but instead printing just f

For this i made modifications to the scull code as:

```
ssize_t memory_read(struct file *filp, char *buf, 
                    size_t count, loff_t *f_pos) { 

  /* Transfering data to user space */ 
  copy_to_user(buf,memory_buffer,5);

  /* Changing reading position as best suits */ 
  if (*f_pos == 0) { 
    *f_pos+=1; 
    return 1; 
  } else { 
    return 0; 
  }
}

ssize_t memory_write( struct file *filp, char *buf,
                      size_t count, loff_t *f_pos) {

  char *tmp;

  tmp=buf+count-1;
  copy_from_user(memory_buffer,tmp,5);
  return 1;
}

int memory_init(void) {
  int result;

  /* Registering device */
  result = register_chrdev(memory_major, "memory", &memory_fops);
  if (result < 0) {
    printk(
      "<1>memory: cannot obtain major number %d\n", memory_major);
    return result;
  }

  /* Allocating memory for the buffer */
  memory_buffer = kmalloc(5, GFP_KERNEL); 
  if (!memory_buffer) { 
    result = -ENOMEM;
    goto fail; 
  } 
  memset(memory_buffer, 0, 5);

  printk("<1>Inserting memory module\n"); 
  return 0;

  fail: 
    memory_exit(); 
    return result;
}
```

Comment: People who downvoted this, thinking it as too naive can infact point to the solution, and the problem i am facing

Comment: This very close to the question I answered yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983153/kernel-driver-reading-ok-from-user-space-but-writing-back-is-always-0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `read` is not correctly implemented. It should not write more then `count` bytes to user (he can have smaller buffer). More relevantly, it should return number of bytes written to user and should return `0` only in case of end of file. It can also return error code as negative number like `-EIO` in case of error.

You write 5 characters, but return 1, so `cat` thinks it is incomplete read, which read 1 byte. I tries to read again and gets 0, so it interprets it as end of file.

`write` has analogous problems, it should also check size of user buffer and return number of bytes.

This is more or less how I would implement `read` for fixed size buffer:

```
ssize_t memory_read(struct file *filp, char *buf, 
                    size_t count, loff_t *f_pos) { 
  ssize_t retval;

  if(down_interruptible(&sem)) // some mutex is probably necessary
    return -ERESTARTSYS;
  count = MIN(count, MEMORY_SIZE - *f_pos);
  if(count == 0) { // this if is probably not necessary
    retval = 0;
    goto out;
  }
  /* Transfering data to user space */ 
  if(copy_to_user(buf, memory_buffer + *f_pos, count)) {
    retval = -EFAULT;
    goto out;
  }
  *f_pos += count;
  retval = count;
out:
  up(&sem);
  return retval;
}
```

Comment: I changed it to: `int bytes=copy_to_user(buf,memory_buffer,5); return bytes` in `memory_read` and same type of return in `memory_write` which hangs the program.

Comment: Can you tell us, if you differ in the opinion of what i have stated. Do you mean some other way?

Comment: @kingsmasher1 - it's not that simple. If `copy_to_user` return non-zero then you should return `-EFAULT`. In case of success you should return number of bytes transfered, which depends on your logic. If you will return 5 it can work in this case.

Comment: Additionally, i guess `tmp=buf+count-1;` should be changed to `tmp=buf` right?

Comment: No use of this: `n=copy_to_user(buf,memory_buffer,count);`

  `/* Changing reading position as best suits */` 
  `if(n != 0)`
    `return -EFAULT;`
  `else`
    `return count;`

Comment: And for write, i changed to (though no use): 

  `tmp=buf;`
  `n=copy_from_user(memory_buffer,tmp,count);`
  `if(n != 0)`
    `return -EFAULT;`
  `else`
    `return count;`

Comment: @kingsmasher1 Now you always return positive, so `cat` will read forever and forever, waiting for end of file. I added the example, maybe you will understand it better.

Comment: Sorry, if i sound too dumb, but what is this `MEMORY_SIZE`?

Comment: @kingsmasher1 - size of the buffer.